# Access the original object instead of returning in powermock-mockito?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

Lets take an example (Note I am using PowerMock - Mockito )

```
Class A {

public void method1(Object obj)
{

}

}
```

Now ,  when we use mockito , we have the api's like when(A.method1(obj2)).thenReturn(obj3);
Instead of returning the customized object obj3 when method gets called , can we access the original object obj passed to method1 in our test case ?

Comment: Have you considered reading up on their documentation? They go through many sample use cases here: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `thenAnswer()`. And I believe the signature should be

```
public Object method1(Object obj)
```

Not sure why would you want to return the same object into the test which your're passing from the test. What actually are you trying to test in this case?

*UPDATE*

Looks like what you're looking for is `ArgumentCaptor`

```
ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
verify(a).method1(captor.capture());
Object realObject = captor.getValue()
```

Comment: but thenAnswer will work only when I call it through my test code , I want the real time object when testing real code.

Comment: @user2181531 if you are looking for something to get the object created in the class-under-test when it calls your mock, then please check my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting , Actually there were zero interactions with this mock , Exception.

Comment: @user2181531 would be easier if you can publish your class-under-test and test code